# Symfony2 Twig and XSL

Tags: xslt, symfony, twig

I am developing an application using symfony2 and twig for templates. The problem comes when trying to use Twig in a XSL file. This is the XSL code with Twig:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    {# src/Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle/Resources/views/Page/testuaanotatu.html.twig #}
    {% extends 'AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

    {% block title %}Testua anotatu{% endblock%}

    {% block body %}

    <div class="box600_lower">
     <xsl:template match="word"> 
       <label>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
           <xsl:text>annotation_checkbox</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
           <xsl:text>Ascripta</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
           <xsl:text>Bscripta</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
           <xsl:text>Cscripta</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
           <xsl:text>checkbox</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </label>
       <label>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
           <xsl:text>altcheckboxoff</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="for">
           <xsl:text>Ascripta</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
           <xsl:text>Bscripta</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </label>
     </xsl:template>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code fails and shows the next message:

Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /var/www/Symfony/web/MyXSLFile.xsl line 12 element template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason for the compilation error is obvious**: An `<xsl:stylesheet>` element cannot have any (non-whitespace only) text node children and in the above code you have:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    {# src/Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle/Resources/views/Page/testuaanotatu.html.twig #}
    {% extends 'AnotatzaileaAnotatzaileaBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

    {% block title %}Testua anotatu{% endblock%}

    {% block body %}
```

Either this text must be removed by some preprocessor, or they need to be wrapped either in a special element, or in a comment.

Comment: The thing is how can I use that text (TWIG code) in the XSL document and not have the compilation error.Thanks.

Comment: As I said before, XSLT doesn't know anything about TWIG. If you want to *generate* it, you must put that text(TWIG code) within an `xsl:template` and further in an `xsl:value-of` or other similar instruction (`xsl:text`).